# report generate with jquery datatable not working

Tags: datatables

Here is a fiddle for demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/rfb93mqs/5/

In the fiddle example if I want to save a report as any format like Csv,Exel,print it contains only One Header...
Is there any way to save the report with multiple Header row??

I am using Datatable v.1.10.10.

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        } );
    } );
    <script>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22592/export-multiple-row-headers

Comment: i think its not working with new version

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: Break up the table into two tables. One table will just have the top row of headers and then load your datatable. Put everything in one div and then use some other method to export everything in that div to pdf etc. I haven't tried it but it's just an idea.